# Possible to pause audio in browser using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, audio, shortcut, web-browsing

I often listen to news/podcasts through my browser (Chrome) on my MacBook and I'd like to figure out a way to pause the audio that is playing using my keyboard instead of trying to hunt down the tab that it's playing in and pausing it there by clicking a button.  I can do this for native apps like Spotify, but not when it's playing through the browser.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I use this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/key-socket-media-keys/fphfgdknbpakeedbaenojjdcdoajihik

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to do it in Chrome, but in Safari it's easy.

Method as follows, in case it would provide a suitable alternative...

You can click on the speaker icon to the right of the address bar to mute either the current tab or all tabs - the Mute wording appears as you hover your cursor.
A single click will mute even if Safari is not currently frontmost, so long as you can see the icon. [It will then bring it to the front, though.]

[image]

You can also set a key command to Mute This Tab or Mute All Tabs in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts >App Shortcuts - though this requires Safari to be frontmost to work.

[image]